# Create bullets for a game at an interval

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have a game, and in it there is a main, controllable character and then enemies that shoot back at the character. For the enemies, when they shoot back I want them to shoot at intervals so that it isn't just one massive block of bullets, and it worked with a setInterval for one, but when a second enemy comes in they don't shoot. Only one of the two will. If anybody has a solution that would be great!

```
            function enemies() {
        if (enemy_soldiers.length == 0) {
            level += 0.2;
            for (var i = 0; i<(1 + Math.floor(Math.round(level))); i++) {
                var gx = 1450
                var gy = getRandom(430, 630);
                enemy_soldiers.push({
                    x: gx,
                    y: gy,
                    l: gl,
                    d: getRandom(350, 600),
                    shooting: false,
                    interval: setInterval (function() {enemy.shooting = true;},fire_rate),
                    shoot: function() {
                        enemy_bullets.push({
                            x: enemy.x+40,
                            y: enemy.y+87,
                            vel: 10,
                    });
                    }
                });
            }
        }
        var enemy;
        gctx.clearRect(0, 0, 1400, 800);
        for (var i in enemy_soldiers) {
            enemy = enemy_soldiers[i];
            drawenemy(enemy.x, enemy.y, enemy.l);
            //ai
            if (distance(enemy.x, enemy.y, cx, cy) >= enemy.d && enemy.x>cx) {
                enemy.x-=vel;
            }
            else if (distance(enemy.x, enemy.y, cx, cy) >= enemy.d && enemy.x<cx) {
                enemy.x+=vel;
            }
            if (distance(enemy.x, enemy.y, cx, cy) <= 600) {
                if (enemy.shooting == true) {
                    enemy.shoot(enemy.x,enemy.y);
                    enemy.shooting = false;
                }
                gbctx.clearRect(0, 0, 1400, 800);
                for (var j in enemy_bullets) {
                    enemy_bullet = enemy_bullets[j];
                    enemy_bullet.x -= enemy_bullet.vel;
                if (enemy_bullet.x > 1400 || enemy_bullet.x < -5 || enemy_bullet.y > 800 || enemy_bullet.y < -5) {
                    enemy_bullets.splice(j,1);
                }
                drawEnemyBullet(enemy_bullet.x, enemy_bullet.y);
            }
        }
    }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution relies on the function Date.now() which returns the current time in milliseconds. It's possible for each enemy to keep track of when they have to fire next and each one can have a different delay between shots.

I've only added a graphic to show when they are firing their weapons, but this can be easily altered to something like a raycast or spawn a projectile particle.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style>
   body {
    background-color: black;
   }
   
   canvas {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    border: solid 1px white;
    border-radius: 1px;
   }
  </style>
 </head>
 
 <body>
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
  <script type="application/javascript">
  
  // Enemy constructor
  function Enemy(x,y) {
   this.x = x;
   this.y = y;
   this.isFiring = false;
   this.fireDelay = (500 + Math.random() * 500) | 0; // Time between shots
   this.lastFired = Date.now(); // Last time at which the enemy fired
  }
  
  /*
   Enemy prototype
   (All objects created using the constructor share these properties)
  
   E.G.
   
    var e1 = new Enemy(10,0);
    var e2 = new Enemy(20,0);
    
    if (e1.__proto__ === e2.__proto__) {
     console.log("Match");
    }
    
    prints "Match"
  */
  Enemy.prototype = {
   WIDTH: 10,
   HEIGHT: 20,
   
   FIRE_DURATION: 100, // Amount of time 'fire' graphic is shown
   FIRE_WIDTH: 10,
   FIRE_HEIGHT: 10,
  
   update: function() {
    // If current time - time when I last fired > the amount of time between shots
    if (Date.now() - this.lastFired > this.fireDelay) {
     this.lastFired = Date.now();
     this.isFiring = true;
     
     // If you were using projectile particles, this is where you would spawn one
    }
    
    if (this.isFiring && Date.now() - this.lastFired > this.FIRE_DURATION) {
     this.isFiring = false;
    }
   },
   
   render: function(ctx) {
    ctx.fillStyle = "darkred";
    ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
    ctx.lineWidth = 2;
    ctx.beginPath();
    
    ctx.rect(
     this.x,
     this.y,
     this.WIDTH,
     this.HEIGHT
    );
    
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();
    
    if (this.isFiring) {
     ctx.fillStyle = "yellow";
     ctx.strokeStyle = "darkyellow";
     ctx.lineWidth = 3;
     ctx.beginPath();
     
     ctx.rect(
      this.x + this.WIDTH,
      this.y + this.HEIGHT * 0.5 - this.FIRE_HEIGHT * 0.5,
      this.FIRE_WIDTH,
      this.FIRE_HEIGHT
     );
     
     ctx.fill();
     ctx.stroke();
    }
   }
  };
  
  var canvasWidth = 180;
  var canvasHeight = 160;
  var canvas = null;
  var ctx = null;
  
  var enemies = [];
  
  window.onload = function() {
   canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
   canvas.width = canvasWidth;
   canvas.height = canvasHeight;
   ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
   
   for (var i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    enemies[i] = new Enemy(20 + i * 3,10 + i * 30);
   }
   
   loop();
  }
  
  function loop() {
   // Update
   for (var i = 0; i < enemies.length; ++i) {
    enemies[i].update();
   }
   
   // Render
   ctx.fillStyle = "gray";
   ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvasWidth,canvasHeight);
   
   for (var i = 0; i < enemies.length; ++i) {
    enemies[i].render(ctx);
   }
   
   //
   requestAnimationFrame(loop);
  }
  
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```